# List of orders from mysql and checkbox in php

Tags: mysql

I have list of orders from `MySQL` in a table, I have put a check box on each row.

I want to select some from them and assign to specific `suppliers(users)`. `Suppliers users` will login to their pages and see the orders which have been assigned to them separately.

Answer (score 0):

what you need is a many to many relationship table

create a table where you will store the user ID and the Order ID.

When you save the list of files with the checkbox et al, save the OrderID and the UserID into the new table.  When the user signs in you need to do something like the following:  (Using PHP syntax);

```
SELECT Orders FROM RelationshipTable WHERE UserID= $MyUserID
```